# How do I setup Red Hat Enterprise Cluster and oracle 9 to support failover?

Tags: oracle, rhel5, cluster

I am trying to figure out how to use RHEL cluster to have automatic failover of an oracle 9 database from one physical machine to another.  Ideally this solution would be fully hardware redundant in that there would be no single piece of hardware that could fail that would take down the database.

I'm happy to get answers that simply point to documentation or even descriptions themselves.

Thanks

edit: I wanted to note that I would like to not have to use oracle RAC or a SAN to keep costs down.

Comment: Which edition are you using? Standart, Enterprise?

Comment: 9.2 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about RHEL cluster or Oracle 9 in particular, but one of my colleagues has just done a Heartbeat/Oracle 10 XE HA installation, and had the good sense to blog about it:

http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2009/07/oracle-why-dost-thou-sucketh-so-prodigiously/
http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2009/08/improving-your-quality-of-life-with-oracle/
http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2009/09/when-ha-wont-play-the-way-you-want-it-to/

Hopefully they'll give you some pointers in the right direction, even if the recipes aren't directly applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 9i introduced RAC (Real Application Cluster) an option that provides software for clustering and high availability.

You should find all the documentation you may need on [metalink](http://metalink.oracle.com), the [Oracle web site](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/clustering/9i/9i_index.html) or the [Interweb](http://www.google.com/search?q=RAC+Oracle+9i).

---

Edit:

If you don't want to use RAC, you could always use [Data Guard](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96653/toc.htm).

Dataguard allows you to synchronize your primary database with up to nine db, called "standby" database.

If your primary server crashes, you just have to open one of the standby databases.

Comment: Oracle RAC costs way too much money to be an option.  I should have specified that in the question.